# fetching user photo or image URL

Tags: blocks, users, media

i am trying to fetch loged in users photo to make a welcome block. i have applied a code which is not working

```
$userphoto = $user->picture;
```

so what to do to fetching user photo or image URL, any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `picture` property of the user entity is the file ID (a reference to the `fid` column in the `file_managed` table).

You can load the file explicitly with [`file_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_load/7) like so:

```
$file = file_load($user->picture);
```

And render it to an image using [`theme_image()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7):

```
$image = theme('image', array(
  'path' => $file->uri,
  'alt' => 'Some alt',
  // etc...
));
```

Alternatively you could dispense with the above and just use the handy [`theme_user_picture()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!theme.php/function/theme_user_picture/7) function:

```
$image = theme('user_picture', array('account' => $account));
```

Comment: thanks for that, but is it possible to get the image path(URL)?

Comment: Sure, just run `$url = file_create_url($file->uri);`, that'll give you a web-accessible URL as opposed to a stream URI

Comment: oh is it my mistakes, it shows only home page address with this error message: `
    Notice: Undefined variable: file in eval() (line 4 of /home/busines/public_html/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
    Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (line 4 of /home/busines/public_html/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
`

Comment: Have you put `$file = file_load($user->picture);` before you run that line?

Comment: Thank you so much Clive .. works great now, i will write again  if any problem happens :)

Comment: one more question this code is not working to show an avatar: `print('<img src='$url' width='100' height='100'>');`

Comment: Common mistake, you're trying to interpolate into a string using single quotes. It should be `print("<img src='$url' width='100' height='100'>");`

Comment: but why it showing this error message: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/busines/public_html/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code on line 7`

Comment: Because your string is delimited with single quotes, and you've also got un-escaped single quotes inside it

Comment: ok no problem i can fix that by adding this code: `print "<img src=" . $url . ">";` but another think, i want to put a style for it called `user_tiny` how to do it? werqious may be write about it below but i can't understand it.

Comment: You need to ask another question really, the comments aren't an appropriate place for extended discussions. You can add a new style at http://mysite.com/admin/config/media/image-styles/add; if you get stuck with that ask another question on here and I'm sure someone will be able to help you out

Comment: I know how to add a image style. i wanna do so to re-size this avatar according to my already created style called `user_tiny` , so that it will not show a full size avatar. So how to add the style while loading the avatar URL. Thanks for your patient :)

Comment: Off the top of my head try `$image = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'user_tiny', 'path' => $file->uri));` (afte you've called `file_load()`)

Comment: another question :) now it fetch the profile avatar but what then if a profile has no avatar? In that case i am getting an error like this: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (line 5 of /home/busines/public_html/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is helpful to render with a image styles

image_style_url('my_image_style',$user->picture['uri']);

second param is a drupal's internal file path like 'public://images/myimage.png'

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$user = user_load($view->result[$key]->uid);
$filepath = $user->picture->uri;
$picture_url = file_create_url($filepath);
```

This will give you the user's picture url.